# minimize select queries on the same table Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I've been trying to figure out how to reduce these **php-mysql** queries to a minimum. I want to maybe write as a single query which will fetch all the data.

---

```
$db_u = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='username'"));
$db_p = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='password'"));
$db_e = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='email'"));
$db_t = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='tag'"));
$db_a = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='active'"));
$db_v = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='version'"));
$db_ti = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='time'"));
$db_wa = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='warn'"));
$data_dis = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='dis'"));
```

---

Doing the above is kind of bogging down the Ram. Any help appreciated.

Checked other questions none fits the bill.

Comment: What does your bot_settings table look like?

Comment: Essentially i just want to grab info from rows where the setting column parameters/vaues i specified correspond. No other column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **IN**   instead of so many queries

```
 SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting IN ('username', 'password','email','tag','active','version','time','warn','dis');
```

Comment: So to access the array will be? Assuming i put it all in one variable.[code]`$db_selected=SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting IN ('username', 'password','email','tag','active','version','time','warn','dis');` How will i access the individual variables in the array?    `$db_selected['username']` ?

Comment: which array you are talking about ?

Comment: I will store the results of the query in an array won't i. To be able to assign them to other variables or echo them.

Comment: for that u can assign a variable to each of the inserted column

Comment: for that you have to do asign the query to a variable like $query ='SElect ....' ;

then  

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['usernamename'];

Comment: So to extract all data per lets say the row where setting column had value of username...`$row['username']`.   But how do i select single values in a column from the row if you get what i mean?

Comment: Yes...i want to be able to retrieve individual data from a matching row.

Comment: let say u have id and name in your table u_settings, u can get individual data by $row['id'] and $row['name']

Comment: I'm talking about getting an individual rows data....how will i identify a row from another since the query wil return multiple rows in the array $row .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, write a single SELECT query with no WHERE clauses. That will grab all the information from the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep each variable, you could create an array and do it this way.

```
$keys = array(
'db_u' => 'username',
'db_p' => 'password',
'db_t' => 'tag'
);

foreach($keys as $key => $value) {
    &$keys[$key] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting='{$value}'"));
}
```

I haven't check the code but I think you get the point. It stores each result in an array.

There is probably an easier way to do this.