# Extracting values from SELECT WHERE IN query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a follow up on [minimize select queries on the same table Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854529/reduce-select-queries-on-the-same-table-mysq). I did not get a full answer on how to extract the individual array values returned by the following query:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting IN
 ('username', 'password','email','tag','active','version','time','warn','dis')");
```

How do I extract any value I want from the **`$result`** array since many rows having the same columns will be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_settings WHERE setting IN
 ('username', 'password','email','tag','active','version','time','warn','dis')");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $settings[$row['setting']] = $row['u_settings'];

print_r($settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) or [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) on `$result`.

**Note:** I would encourage you to upgrade to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), instead of the [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) mysql_* functions.